# Sums of angles and trigonometric values

Tags: trigonometry, angle

Are there any formulae where an angle and e.g. the sin of an angle are added/subtracted together.

I know of infinite series  such as,

$\sin\theta=\frac{\theta}{1}-\frac{\theta^3}{3!}+\frac{\theta^5}{5!}-...$

and approximations like,

$\cos\theta \approx 1-{\frac {\theta ^{2}}{2}}$

I am interested in exact finite formulae containing angles and trigonometric functions  such as,

$\theta + a\sin k\theta $

Comment: Well, you probably already know about [these](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_trigonometric_identities#Angle_sum_and_difference_identities) ... there are also [these](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_trigonometric_identities#Sines_and_cosines_of_sums_of_infinitely_many_terms)

Comment: [Somewhat relevant, although the answer given is only a numerical approximation](http://mathcentral.uregina.ca/qq/database/QQ.09.00/roble1.html)

Comment: Thanks Zubin. The first ones seem to have trigonometric values added together or with numbers. I'd like one adding an angle and a trigonometric value.

Comment: Is there a particular problem / application you need those identities for?

Comment: The interesting case would be where some meaning can be attached to an expression of this sort.  See for example the perimeter of a [circular segment](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/CircularSegment.html).  A different sort of "addition" involving derivatives is given in the model of [a simple pendulum](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pendulum_(mathematics)): $$\frac{d^2\theta}{dt^2} + k\sin \theta = 0$$

Comment: @ZubinMukerjee - (I'm embarrassed to say) it concerns  a non-mathematical equation in a [puzzle](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/54515/tricky-trigonometrical-triangle-teaser)

Comment: @hardmath Wow, the circular segment calculation you linked seems to be exactly the kind of adding (*subtracting) desired!

Comment: @Tom In your puzzle, is $\alpha =96^\circ$ (as one of the answerers assumed)? What is $\alpha$? I suspect that if $\alpha \neq 96^\circ$, then the puzzle might not have anything to do with math :)

Comment: @ZubinMukerjee, $\alpha \neq 96^\circ$ and as you suspect that equation is not meant to be taken as mathematical (there is a little use of elementary triangle geometry after that 'equation' is translated).